# Yii themes - on what scenario?

Tags: yii

We have been using Yii for building web applications. Once in a while, **themes** comes to our discussion table.

But, if we have a web application and we wish to change the look and feel only, we may, as well, change the **public_html** folder, since the structure will be similar.

The only point we see on having themes is for those cases where we may want to dynamically (user choice by clicking on a "change layout button") change the look and feel of an application.

Does anyone uses **themes** for any other proposes, or configurations?

Comment: Themes are great if you want to set up a copy of a site with a different look. The logic stays the same, you only modify the design elements. You should also consult the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming

Comment: @Ors: I don't quite see specifically what is the advantage there. When you setup a project without themes, you already have the design elements separated. I mean, you can, as easily copy that same project structure and change the css, js, and views there. - Do you see my point? - Please advice because that is exactly the point that I'm not getting.

Comment: @MEM I agree with you, that you don't need themes if you don't plan to let the user change the look of your site. Therefore I almost never use themes in my projects. This also keeps the directory structure more clean IMO.

Answer (score 0):

We use themes to great effect. We operate 6 sites using as single instance of a Yii application. The theme is then selected based on the domain name.

Yes we could have just used 6 different application folders and served them separately. This comes with several advantages though, which you've probably already dismissed if they're not relevant to you, but here they are:

- Shared code, updates and maintenance are far easier
- Adding a new theme is much cleaner IMO (just a new theme folder rather than a whole application directory)
- Global assets, which are then overridden easily in the theme, rather than wiping over them completely, you'r expanding them.
- Shared Cache, the whole application caches to a single directory, view cache, data cache etc.
- Shared Assets directory, assets are only published once ( although this could in theory be set up in a copied environment)

I much prefer this set up, it looks far cleaner just to **override** rather than **overwrite**. Plus really, I can't think of a reason why copying the whole directory would be better than this method, yes there are issues in theming that have to be worked out, but copying the whole source doesn't solve them.

Comment: We have also considered that option. But in order to make such a switch, it will be much more then a Yii change of structure. Our all workflow would have to change as well. And that's something we can't afford and we don't see the need. About the copy of ALL application directory, well, actually, you don't copy the all directory. You take out public_html form protected/ and your good to go. :)

Comment: Ah so you've got a slightly different application structure anyway so it is a little easier for you. The default is to have `protected` within `public_html` so it would be a little more difficult.